# How to get text data in front of different emoji's present in different lines

Tags: node.js, regex

> I have many messages like this, how can i parse the message to get the corresponding text in that line.

For Example:- message here is like this.

```
Where do you live?


1️⃣  Bangalore

2️⃣  Mangalore

3️⃣  None of the above


Choose one option 1,2,3.
```

My desired output in this case should be a map with given key & values, so       that i can use the same in my code:-

```
1 -> Bangalore

2 -> Mangalore

3 -> None of the above
```

**UPDATE:- Added the code that worked for me.**

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: I have not written any code till now. I have attached the snippet of the output i require, above with the question.
Basically I have a message as given above and i have to parse it to create a map containing values present in the line after that emoji. @Toto

Comment: @SID_2: Could you get a solution to your problem? Also, in your first part of text, those numbers appear binary like `1️⃣ ` or `2️⃣ ` Can you fix that data? or is that intentional?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I have added the solution to this question, you can have a loot at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Code that I finally used to get the work done.

```
function isNumEmoji(word) {
    var emoji =  ['0️⃣', '1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣', '7️⃣', '8️⃣', '9️⃣'];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
        if (emoji[i] === word) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getMcqButtonsText(message) {
    var mcqButtonText = [];
    var sentences = message.split(/\r?\n/);
    for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i += 1) {
        var words = sentences[i].split(' ');
        var curSentence = '';
        var isEmojiPrev = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j += 1) {
            if (isNumEmoji(words[j])) {
                isEmojiPrev = true;
                curSentence = '';
            } else if (isEmojiPrev === true) {
                curSentence += words[j] + ' ';
            }
        }
        if (isEmojiPrev === true) {
            mcqButtonText.push(curSentence.trim());
        }
    }
    var result = {
        buttonText: mcqButtonText
    };
    return result;
}
```

Here the array "buttonText" will contain the text present in front of emoji in each sentence on the message.